# Windows Batch: Split String to individual characters to variables

Tags: windows, string, variables, batch-file

in Windows Batch, if I had a variable (length can change) that was, for example: "hello world!"
is it possible to "split" the variable so each character is its own variable so the output could look like:

```
t1=h
t2=e
t3=l
etc.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: There are 3 methods at least: get first char. and eliminate it in a `goto` loop (slowest), get length of string and use a `for /L` loop to access each char. (fastest), and use `cmd /U | find` trick (simplest).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set str="hello world^!"
set tempstr=%str%
set count=0
:loop
if defined tempstr (
    set tempstr=%tempstr:~1%
    set /a count+=1
    set /a pos=%count%-1
    set t!count!=!str:~%pos%,1!
    goto loop
)

:: check the generated variables
set t
```

To get the nth character in a string, use `set char=%str:~n,1%`. 
I hope this was helpful!

Comment: would be even more helpful, if you would actually *use* delayed expansion (hint: `count`)

Comment: ...or, within `set /A`, do neither use `%` nor `!`: `set /a pos=count-1`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant using `for /L` to iterate over all characters of the string. The number of characters, so the length of the string, is retrieved in sub-routine `:LENGTH` first:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_STRING=Hello world!"

call :LENGTH LEN "%_STRING%"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%I in (0,1,%LEN%) do (
    set "$CHR[%%I]=!_STRING:~%%I,1!"
)
set $CHR
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B


:LENGTH  rtn_length  val_string
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set /A "RET=0" & set "STR=%~2"
if defined STR set /A "RET=1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%L in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if not "!STR:~%%L,1!"=="" (
        set /A "RET+=%%L"
        set "STR=!STR:~%%L!"
    )
)
(
    endlocal
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%RET%"
)
exit /B
```

---

Here is a different variant, using `cmd /U` to convert the string into Unicode, where a null-byte becomers inserted behind every character, and `find`, which treats these null-bytes like end-of-line markers:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_STRING=Hello world!"

set /A "IDX=0"
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('
    cmd /U /V /C echo^(!_STRING!^| find /V ""
') do (
    set "CHR=%%I"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /F "delims=" %%J in ("$CHR[!IDX!]=!CHR!") do (
        endlocal
        set "%%J"
    )
    set /A "IDX+=1"
)
set $CHR

endlocal
exit /B
```

---

Finally, here is another variant, based on a `goto` loop. This uses a position pointer `POS` to scan the string and to extract a single character. If no character is returned, the end of the string is reached:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_STRING=Hello world!"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if not defined _STRING goto :QUIT
set /A "POS=0"
:LOOP
set "CHR=!_STRING:~%POS%,1!"
if defined CHR (
    set "$CHR[%POS%]=!CHR!"
    set /A "POS+=1"
    goto :LOOP
)
:QUIT
set $CHR
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but accepted answer misses letter d?
Changed

`set /a pos=%count%-1` to

`set /a pos=!count!-1`

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set str="hello world!"
set tempstr=%str%
set count=0
:loop
if defined tempstr (
    set tempstr=%tempstr:~1%
    set /a count+=1
    set /a pos=!count!-1
    set t!count!=!str:~%pos%,1!
    goto loop
)

:: check the generated variables
set t
pause
```

Here is another version.
variables start with 0, though

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var="hello world!"
rem remove quotes
set var=%var:"=%

rem add limiter
set var=%var%_

echo %var%

set count=0

:loop
set tempvar=!var:~%count%,1!
if !tempvar!==_ goto skip
set arr!count!=!tempvar!
set /a count=!count!+1
goto loop

:skip
echo out

echo display output
set arr

pause
```