# Batch Split String to individual variables

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd, split

[Windows Batch: Split String to individual characters to variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576914/windows-batch-split-string-to-individual-characters-to-variables)

Trying to do this but in a function of its own.

I have a 4 digit number that I am trying to split into distinct variables but If there is a way to do it so that it would work for someone who doesn't know how many variables they are using I would prefer that. The following is my code so far.

```
REM @echo off
setlocal
:start
set /p nStore="Enter 4 digit store number:"
call :split nStore n1 n2 n3 n4
:pass2
echo %result%
echo %n1%
goto :eof

:split <nStore> <n1> <n2> <n3> <n4>
(
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "tmpStore=!%~1!"
    set "count=0"
    :loop
    if defined tmpStore
    (
        set tmpStore=%tmpStore:~1%
        set /a count+=1
        set /a pos=%count%-1
        set n!count!=!str:~%pos%,1!
        goto loop
    )
    endlocal
    goto :pass2
)
```

When I call the :split I keep getting an error "The Syntax of the command is incorrect". Right now I am trying to get :split to store my 4 digit "store number" into variables. So if my store number is 9876 I expect n1 = 9 n2 = 8 n3 = 7 n4 = 6 as variables. Question being what is wrong with my code that it errors out.

Comment: That's nonsense code, a goto can't pass an argument use call instead.

Comment: Bah! Sorry about that. Should be fixed now

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Keeps saying that the syntax of the command is incorrect. I can't get it to work. :/

Comment: You should read what a [mcve] is. I don't know what you expect or try to achieve.

Comment: In general: [**Never** use `:label` nor `:: label-like comment` inside a command block enclosed in `()` parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32147995/3439404). Remove `()` surrounding body of `:split` procedure. **2**. Remove all `<` and `>` from `:split <nStore> <n1> <n2> <n3> <n4>` line (`:split` should be necessary and sufficient). **3**. return from a procedure using `goto :eof` instead of `goto :pass2`. **4**. Think about `endlocal` inside the `:split` procedure. **5**. , **6**., …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
REM @echo off
setlocal
:start
set /p nStore="Enter 4 digit store number:"
call :split nStore n1 n2 n3 n4
:pass2
echo %result%
echo %nstore% %n1% %n2% %n3% %n4%
goto :eof

:split <nStore> <n1> <n2> <n3> <n4>
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "n4=!%~1!"
endlocal&SET "n4=%n4%"
SET "n1=%n4:~0,1%"
SET "n2=%n4:~1,1%"
SET "n3=%n4:~2,1%"
SET "n4=%n4:~3,1%"
GOTO :EOF
```

You don't need to send the destination parameter names to the subprocedure. You could send `%nstore%` instead of `nstore` to avoid needing to invoke `delayed expansion`

...actually, you *could* avoid `delayedexpansion` using

```
for /f "tokens=1,2delims==" %%a in (`set %1`) do if /i "%%a"=="%1" set "n4=%%b"
```

If using delayedexpansion, you need the `endlocal...` to make the value of `n4` available outside of the `setlocal/endlocal` bracket.

Theremainder of the code is self-evident. You aren't setting `result`, so *that* `echo` will resolve to `echo` hence provide an `echo-status` report. I've changed the second `echo` to provide a list of all of the variables in question.

And of course there's no checking done that the input data is of length 4 or of only-numerics.

Comment: I removed the checking due to Lotpings Comment of minimal code usage to explain the problem. Accidently left `result` in there. I have it in my current script and it works. This works! Thank you. Why does GOTO: EOF work instead of going back up to something like :pass2?

Comment: A `call` statement transfers execution to the target label and processing then continues until you either reach end-of-file or an `exit` statement, at which point it will return to the statement following the `call`. I habitually add `goto :eof` even where it is redundant in order that I don't need to remember to insert it before any new subroutines I may add to the code. `exit` comes in a number of flavours. `exit` unadorned will terminate the `cmd` session. `exit /b n` where `n` is optional and numeric will set `errorlevel` to `n` and terminate a subroutine.

Comment: Thanks! That helps me alot. Sorry for the basic understanding. This helps with other parts of the script I haven't gotten to yet.